# What is the best way to post parameter into APIs?

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

Like some of the senior developers of my company are saying I am posting data in the wrong way. I want to know which way is best.

Basically, we send data in Body Parameter like:-

```
// In Retrofit or Volley or AndroidFastNetworking

My way :- addBodyParameter("Key",value)

Senior Way :- addBodyParameter(jsonObject)
```

like what he is arguing with me is we must send parameters in a jsonObject even if we have one key or multiple keys.

Can anyone suggest to me which way is best ?? I forgot one thing he is an ios developer.

Answer (score 1):

By using GsonRequest you can post data over API. Gson is a library for converting Java objects to and from JSON using reflection.

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Listener<T> listener;

/**
 * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
 *
 * @param url URL of the request to make
 * @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
 * @param headers Map of request headers
 */
public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
        Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(
                response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(
                gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your senior's (iOS developer) way is better. I will explain why. It is easy for Webservice/API guy to create object from jsonString which you have send him as a request, so that he gets all inputs all at ones. While in other hand if you send multiple objects to Webservice/API in request. Backenf guy has to do lot of manupulation. I hope you have understud.

**UPDATE**

**Difference**

> Sending JsonObject

**Advantages**

1. Backend and Frontend both developers has to create exact same classes, so that while sending and receiving data can be processed properly.
2. Easy to convert Object to jsonString or vice versa. (like GSON in android).
3. Need to write less code.
4. Good for large objects

**Disadvantage**

1. Both developers need great coordination if some one makes any changes in Objects needs to modify to other developer.
2. Create a bit confussion while creating large objects.(such as lists inside a object)

> Sending Parameters

**Advantages**

1. Good for one or two premitive parameters (int, String, boolean etc). Not for large objects. If you send multiple custom object it makes no sense, create single object otherwise.

**Disadvantage**

1. Need to write more code.
2. Not at all good for large objects (As I explained above)

Comment: There is only one parameter in a api and also the backend guy doesn't have any problem with it. do i need to create jsonObject even if we have one parameter? because in ios its hard to send string object in httpBody they have to convert string to dta then utf-8 then only api will give response otherwise not.

Comment: I don't know about iOS. If backend guy doesn't have any problem with it go for it. But most of experience and professional developers doesn't recommend this.

Comment: Even if you have one parameter you should create jsonObject.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. i want more explanation on this topic like whats the diff. . thanks for your help.